# PHPUnit "linking" functions

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm writing unit tests for a project I'm working on and I'm trying to figure out how to effectively write tests to test this.

I currently have the following methods:

- Object::createNew()
- Object->delete()

My concern is how do I write unit tests to properly test this effectively because I'm having a hard time thinking about how to "tie" these functions together. So for example,

```
<?php

public function testObjectCreation() {
    $object = Object::createNew("my parameters");

    // ... asserts

    // I don't want to keep the object so I delete it
    // but I don't want test that deleting works here too, I want to separate it
    $object->delete();
}

// Where would I get an object to test that deleting works?
public function testObjectDeletion() {
    // ...stuff
    $object->delete();
}

public function testUnrelatedObjectFunctions () {}
```

So my question is, how could I feed one object to the other function. Would I have to make `testObjectCreation()` be static and then feed it to `testObjectDeletion()` with `@dataProvider` or would I have to store $object in a private/protected variable that would only be used in these two functions? If I make it static, wouldn't I lose access to the assert functions provided by PHPUnit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a good case for the [@depends](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html) annotation. This allows you to return something in one test and use it as a parameter in another.

Here is an example from the phpunit docs:

```
public function testEmpty()
{
    $stack = array();
    $this->assertEmpty($stack);

    return $stack;
}

/**
 * @depends testEmpty
 */
public function testPush(array $stack)
{
    array_push($stack, 'foo');
    $this->assertEquals('foo', $stack[count($stack)-1]);
    $this->assertNotEmpty($stack);

    return $stack;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much